# Searching from model and related model in laravel5

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I want to keyword search from a table and its all related table using Elequent in Laravel5.
My controller is

```
 $clients = Client::with('contacts', 'paymentTerm', 'addressInfo');
    if ($q = Request::input("q")) {
        $clients->where("clients.name", 'LIKE', "%$q%");
        $clients->where("address_info.email", 'LIKE', "%$q%");//This is not working,I want to search from both client and client address_info
    }
    return $clients->paginate(10);
```

Client Model ,

```
 public function addressInfo() {
    return $this->hasOne('App\Model\ClientAddressInfo');
}
```

Client Address info,

```
public function client() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Model\Client');
    }
```

how can I apply keyword search here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `whereHas` to filter by a related model:

```
$clients->whereHas('addressInfo', function($query) use ($q){
    $query->where("email", 'LIKE', "%$q%");
});
```

Comment: Thank you for answer and it is working,but the problem is two conditions are joining here with "and", how it make "or" ?

Comment: Simply use `orWhereHas` instead of `whereHas` (it works the same as with two "normal" `where`s)

Comment: How can i sort from related model `$clients->orderBy('addressInfo.email');`?

Comment: Unfortunately that's just possible if you use a join. [See this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23530051/1903366)

Comment: So I need to change Elequent  method to db method ?

Comment: You can still use Eloquent but not the relation