# Sort data based on count with sub-relationship in Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have three tables, `users`, `branches` and `jobs`. `users` table has one-to-one relationship with `branches` table and one-to-many relationship with `jobs` table. Branches are responsible for uploading jobs and `users` table can include various categories including branch. Both `branches` and `jobs` table has user_id as a foreign key. **Now I want to obtain the branches list with number of jobs uploaded by them and also sort them by highest number of uploads first.**

I am able to display list of branches along with the number of jobs they posted as in the following code, but I want to sort according to the number of jobs posted. How can I achieve that?

```
@foreach(\App\Branch::all() as $branchesJob) 
<div class="col-lg-3 col-xs-3">
  <div class="small-box bg-olive-active">
    <div class="inner">
      <h3>{{\App\Job::where('user_id','=',$branchesJob->user->id)->count()}}</h3>
      <p>{{$branchesJob->branch_name}}</p>
    </div>
    <a class="small-box-footer" href="{{(route('admin.branch_job.show',$branchesJob->id))}}">
                                            More info
                                            <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i>
                                        </a>
  </div>
</div>
@endforeach
```

Comment: It would be usefull if you posted your table structure instead of just explaining it

Comment: why you doing your database call in your view ?? It's a bad practice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for the reply. I was able to do it by using `sortBy()` and `count()` methods.

```
$user = \App\User::where('category','=','Branch')->with('job')->get()->sortBy(function($u){
        return count($u->job);
 }, $options = SORT_REGULAR, $descending = true);
```

Thanks to this post!
  [Laravel OrderBy relationship count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24208502/laravel-orderby-relationship-count)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get it done retrieving all your records in the template. And you won't be able to do it through a separate aggregate function (counting the relations).

I would do it with a join clause with an order by, as the marked-correct answer explains here:
[Laravel Eloquent sort by relation table column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23530051/laravel-eloquent-sort-by-relation-table-column)