# how to sort query results with nested relation column field in laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

```
$props = Property::with(['rentalUnit','rentalUnit.floor'])->get()->toArray();
```

I want to sort `rentalunit` collection with field of floor table field `floor_name`

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel Eloquent sort by relation table column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23530051/laravel-eloquent-sort-by-relation-table-column)

Comment: i want it do without join

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to your Property model

```
public function rentalUnitOrderByFloorName() 
{
    return $this->rentalUnit()->select('rental_units.*', 'floors.name')->leftJoin('floors', 'floors.rental_unit_id', '=', 'rental_units.id')->orderBy('floors.name');
}
```

Then

```
$props = Property::with(['rentalUnitOrderByFloorName','rentalUnitOrderByFloorName.floor'])->get()->toArray();
```

Comment: In this situation, make a join!

Comment: if i am applying join than it removing some rows from results  i want

Comment: Left join won't do that!

Comment: i have already try with it left join but i want it without join